# KrakenD plugin read config setting

Tags: go, plugins, krakend

I have written a simple server plugin for KrakenD Gateway in GO language. It injects the code before routing starts.
I am trying to read a config setting from my `krakend.json` to pass the setting to my plugin at startup. Below I used the setting `mysetting` as an example (please see the code between the comments `HERE THE READ OF MY SETTING STARTS/ENDS`).

How can I use the value of `mysetting` from the config inside the plugin?

Here is my `krakend.json` config file that is used as the `-c` argument on startup:

```json
{
  "version": 2,
  "timeout": "3000ms",
  "cache_ttl": "300s",
  "output_encoding": "json",
  "name": "Gateway",
  "plugin": {
    "pattern": ".so",
    "folder": "./plugins/"
  },
  "extra_config": {
    "github_com/devopsfaith/krakend/transport/http/server/handler": {
      "name": "testPlugin",
      "mysetting": "Hello"
    }
  },
  "endpoints": [
    ...
  ],
  "port": 9010,
}
```

Here is the code for the registerHandlers function:

```golang
func (r registerer) registerHandlers(ctx context.Context, extra map[string]interface{}, _ http.Handler) (http.Handler, error) {
    
        // check the passed configuration and initialize the plugin
        name, ok := extra["name"].(string)
        
        if !ok {
            return nil, errors.New("wrong config")
        }
        
        if name != string(r) {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("unknown register %s", name)
        }

        //************ HERE THE READ OF MY SETTING STARTS ************
        
        setting, ok := extra["mysetting"].(string)

        if !ok {
            return nil, errors.New("mysetting missing in config")
        }

        fmt.Printf("PLUGIN: My custom setting: %s\n", setting)
        
        //************ HERE THE READ OF MY SETTING ENDS ************
        
        // return the actual handler wrapping or your custom logic so it can be used as a replacement for the default http handler
        return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
            fmt.Fprintf(w, "%s, %q", setting, html.EscapeString(req.URL.Path))
        }), nil
}
```

Comment: Please stop reposting the same question over and over again, edit it instead and ask for it to be reopened. If you keep doing this, you'll just end up banned. And you need to give more details, "it's not working" is not helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself. When building the sample code for the question I noticed it works exacly the way it is coded in the question.